# gdb crash in my Qt project

Tags: windows, qt, gdb, mingw

I have installed Qt libraries, minGW and Creator with net-install. If I run application without debug it is work successful, but if I use debug - system alert "unexpected output: gdb crash".

My system:

- Qt 4.8.0
- minGW 4.4
- Windows 7 SP1 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I deleted minGW, what been installed by Qt, and 
installed it(minGW) from offical site. Now it's work correctly.